# R code to get Log-likelihood for Binary logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, log-likelihood

I have developed a binomial logistic regression using glm function in R. I need three outputs which are
Log likelihood (no coefficients)
Log likelihood (constants only)
Log likelihood (at optimal)

What functions or packages do I need to obtain these outputs?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no coefficients" vs "constants only"? `logLik()` will get you the MLE.  By the way, the `lme4` package doesn't have a `glm` function: do you mean `glmer()` ? Also, see "Deviance and log-likelihood of GLMMs" in `?logLik.merMod`

Comment: I made a mistake. The GLm I used came from the basic Stat package. I would try those functions now. I should be asking the most basic question: the constant only model is like this 'y~1' right?

Comment: Can you edit your question to fix your mistake? It would also be useful to clarify "no coefficients" vs "constants only"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a fitted model `m`.

log-likelihood of full model (i.e., at MLE): `logLik(m)`

log-likelihood of intercept-only model: `logLik(update(m, . ~ 1))`

although the latter can probably be retrieved without refitting the model if we think carefully enough about the `deviance()` and `$null.deviance` components (these are defined with respect to the *saturated model*)

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...